# How to get all hosts mapped to a particular appserver or port in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, appserver

I have one ML Box lets say **abc**

I have attached below mentioned hosts to **abc**

```
 abc1
 abc2
 abc3
 abc4
 abc5
```

Only abc1,abc2 and abc5 can access **Manage (8002 port)** app server.

I mean beow mentioned are the correct ones

```
abc1:8002
abc2:8002
abc5:8002
```

If we try to access `abc3:8002` or `abc4:8002` we'll get error.

Is there any way or API which can get me all the hosts having access to `8002 port`

In the above example output will be `abc1,abc2 and abc5`

Comment: I don't understand your question. abc1 through abc5 do *not* have MarkLogic installed? Does abc1:8002 mean that abc1 has Apache HTTP server (or equivalent) set up to route traffic to abc:8002?

Comment: Is MarkLogic installed on each of the 5 hosts? Are all 5 hosts part of the same cluster? Are all 5 hosts in the same MarkLogic Group? Can you also please post the error that you see when trying to access abc3:8002 and abc4:8002?

Comment: Also, are you able to access port 8001 on all 5 hosts? If you can, let us know what the status of the 8002 app server is for the two hosts that aren't working.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have assigned some of your hosts to a Group different than `Default`.

App-servers are defined per Group. Each host in the same Group shares the same app-servers. The out of the box Default group has `App-Services` (8000), `Admin` (8001), and `Manage` (8002). However, if you create additional groups, only `Admin` comes out of the box with the new groups. You will have to replicate `App-Services`, and `Manage` manually.

[Roxy](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy) has features to create groups, and will add those app-servers to new groups automatically for you.

HTH!